# Problem when generating pdf (BytesIO / canvas): return incomprehensives characters in web browser instead of uploading pdf

Tags: python, django

I habe deploy my django app on pythonanywhere but have an error with export in excel

my code works except on pythonanywhere

I had FileWrapper but it doesn't work. Instead of openning a pdf files, it display this:

`` %PDF-1.3 %���� ReportLab Generated PDF document http://www.reportlab.com 1 0 obj << /F1 2 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding /Name /F1 /Subtype /Type1 /Type /Font >> endobj 3 0 obj << /BitsPerComponent 8 /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB /Filter [ /ASCII85Decode /FlateDecode ] /Height 161 /Length 23591 /Subtype /Image /Type /XObject /Width 277 >> stream Gb"/lG>qMqp@&$+mJ#IcpYKseYrD#T/D+V;,#rq('Lbh!6)5rc,/#BI!bn(rcJB*TQN"8&/+nC0RJHn;**\]eIJ;;2J`WmRS&:*c_k6E@a@)8:qK(4Bq94Ym6^k*l<@!l@u&m6nPY[E;=(`uka6l(^l/6F)(`Wm81OTjbI$^SkcnUUj:AAS&VJgI^1Hsjc'=YN%D@#6EO+'>a8(5rbT=<\-m#8SkQ"lf[mQH4[JJH\\W_>(ft-*gp+@)3IY0Ku^KM(BJc=Kk1/N"7IA+q)Bq(+bROir][TaF`r5"\WCBpqVJ-ZMq<-N/W3+q=aD6p^^#GSK3,!m=5,S^k0O(IgJ;]"cTV8QDoqsP)5F$G:ASk+`DV'\=H?8[mPrHAG]\,F1'-[G=@:5^,Jtd1fd!KHZV2(cL*!pJgH$JI!f["KIFrb8XF6tbDM\_e?5,"rn]iuManl7S\-Vb3HFdWU=T7oXnD_,Zh]s"Rt%uTiLfkQr,R;QJ*q7N-$Jmp+7GZm@*?;_c6)NDlC>gdJd"e(rQ4gC%1OW9*=lKH59i)d*kctfoX9%k%1g-8D00Rj_W[!ZNY.n-:L_GZh+R2)?M\WefQb&I)&Q0C/UP'Yq(p.SO*CSS$?Dc@l[]6*Hh=5p"2^CN3\B%V6J.TL;;qtXTeZQopil>5d@5TAfs1%,`8\B[G%,YKIIN5e7scVgo1X2D,Ote]5-?q-3r8fA":Ne)lHd;%=^(CQffEAcC$<-X7rFe<%;a;_Kf=3,]!Z%qm@B/FFtLG7MoEtPdf\5?a+qXZngD$c`,"aS+;;K\H=4RX(&\I6F>0,fRW:^;s&\umh]p)V6ufGPCZhGH]3+i!N8Xl,T&&2!B,mOVqj+lm=GOJ:"h$RurXSePp^@ZBJ+dup-MDp5[a'pF?O5;@g:h5/T.0-2:!WnOFs_QRb?mfBGeSC@/XbdWpnZ&Xc%(5r&%s<_T6Zj!-SM'1H"HCb$sPE'YnA79Bg"@V3X:[s5j'J"`Z;,MG=a^\FVLM*=&KEC=RW\RBHqJH8K/`cN^1A@=&#\Z[*;+7s%61,SEH]-JfTBJU-b]GCbjm`mV6;-\^Y60T`K'spmmidk4`Kd&+Z%g-DO4*V`aY!HB^EQC!CQ=f>aj1Rd@%;NZF[hhkQkK^s@s$/dYT,JX0aYBo5X8d)tLjHd\DXqKmOG1;7:R"[ktb%pJqXYUpDJh`SA>3B+D02MTQ=koO/&K/%bn9TL_04tM9uji-(*LqT!V*l$mi7*0]r'j9mN_^Ck3O4($BPuXe5X4"d[Kgn,AcKYhGeX>^L8=*\>[8@qc*;fh])V.]_=i]]hk=)!hs!)LE5H\r"ou>PdiS,,5q!cJ;$2!#MQl[[@@H6r_ArN:*(->nhlmR[c%b1U\p)l'b5Cda4LD;9n#:R`TRQ^Alq9qAeCYdrW1N$R%Oo[Y-7k$kgfoFKMB:<1ZpY.q!<_>s%3C]U]H.0lstM)+ai-fi5=ff-*c+]1-O[aN11lAg8[j>[:R[&s0.t%lY"[_iA8j4s8K=!cgq+I[f3at/J("ZoRq'#_hVUENO)GOpnRqKS`Q'f@#ouKMeN8k#mq)$!f#B=u_VWui*,sUsL_tp>h/,44oZog0Goiq6AK/_+hj)]j,c^%#Wmb&kse0mr%/n`m"DiNGr)"f8:hb.2M\Sn[ZplmT&2j"">c:r2qoLT/HbaOXRfA[!UJqFY*&o?[7p^m^J`*dlD263B0k%p].h\EClOB2[T:Dj@_l.I0QJD?-< ``

how to fix this issue?

views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import time
import io
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from parameters.models import Thesaurus
# http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-an-update-view-with-a-Django-form-in-Django.php
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
# from django.contrib import messages
from werkzeug.wsgi import FileWrapper
from randomization.models import Preinclusion, Randomisation, Medicament, ListeRandomisation, Randomiser, is_randomized, is_randomizable, reattribuer_medicament, email
from parameters.models import Profile, Pays, Region, Site, Thesaurus
from .forms import RandomisationForm, ReallocationForm
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

# création du pdf de résultat de la randomisation ou de la réattribution d'un traitement
# paramètre get['type'] (1/2) en fonction du type d'édition
# 1 : randomisation / 2 : reallocation
@login_required
def pdf(request):
    # Create a file-like buffer to receive PDF data.
    buffer = io.BytesIO()

    # Create the PDF object, using the buffer as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)
...
    # FileResponse sets the Content-Disposition header so that browsers
    # present the option to save the file.
    buffer.seek(0)

    return FileResponse(FileWrapper(buffer), as_attachment=True, filename=form + ' ' + pat +'.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the response is missing a *Content-Type* in your response.

```
return FileResponse(FileWrapper(buffer), content_type='application/pdf')
```

The FileWrapper is used to send the content of the PDF in chunks. So you need to manually set the *Content-Type* and *Content-Length* response headers.

But in your case, since the content of the PDF is already in memory (inside your *buffer* variable), you should be able to just pass the buffer into the response. You don't really  need to load it in chunks as FileWrapper does.